# convert elisp event string / vector to EVENT object

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Elisp, I need to use (event-modifiers EVENT) to determine if last event involves any modifier keys pressed. I'm using read-key-sequence/read-key-sequence-vector to capture the event. The prior returns a string while the later returns a vector. Neither seems to qualify as a valid EVENT type argument. How can I convert a key sequence string or a vector to such EVENT object? Thanks.

Comment: If you specifically want to read a *single* event, use `read-event`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `event-modifiers` expects a single event.  A key sequence is in general not a single event. See the code defining `describe-key`, in `help.el`, for an example of analyzing the events in a key sequence.  E.g., this bit:

```
    ;; If KEY is a down-event, read and include the
    ;; corresponding up-event.  Note that there are also
    ;; down-events on scroll bars and mode lines: the actual
    ;; event then is in the second element of the vector.
    (and (vectorp key)
     (let ((last-idx (1- (length key))))
       (and (eventp (aref key last-idx))
        (memq 'down (event-modifiers (aref key last-idx)))))
     (or (and (eventp (aref key 0))
          (memq 'down (event-modifiers (aref key 0)))
          ;; However, for the C-down-mouse-2 popup
          ;; menu, there is no subsequent up-event.  In
          ;; this case, the up-event is the next
          ;; element in the supplied vector.
          (= (length key) 1))
         (and (> (length key) 1)
          (eventp (aref key 1))
          (memq 'down (event-modifiers (aref key 1)))))
     (read-event))
```

Answer (score 2):

You gave the answer in your question: /...if last event.../, so you want to use the last element of the event sequence returned by `read-key-sequence-vector`.  E.g. `(aref keys (1- (length keys))`.